# find command works differently in zsh and bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I just switched my shell from bash to zsh and I noticed  some different behavior as to how the find command works.

In my old bash shell I had a function that basically replicates the behavior of the find command. For some strange reason the find command does not work in `zsh` but works in my old `bash`

Command in bash

```
~ /java_src: f stringBuf*
./com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/utils/StringBufferPool.java
./java/io/StringBufferInputStream.java
./java/lang/StringBuffer.java
```

Same command in zsh

```
~ /java_src: f stringBuf*
zsh: no matches found: stringBuf*
```

This is the function

```
# find shorthand
function f() {
     find . -iname "$1"
 }
```

Any suggestions on why that might be the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try quoting the argument, as in `f 'stringBuf*'`, to avoid premature glob expansion.

If you call it unquoted, `bash` will do the smart thing and, after looking for the pattern in your current directory and not finding anything, will pass the parameter to the function as is.

`zsh` on the other hand, will try to match the pattern in your current directory, then complain about not finding anything, and not execute the function at all.

It is generally not a good idea to use unquoted wildcards (unless you mean it), since, if you have a file in your current directory called, say, "stringBuffoon", your parameter to `f` will be turned into "stringBuffoon", and the search will not give you the results you expect.